# Can someone help me in reducing my php code?

Tags: php

My HTML CODE

```
<div id="port" align="center">
    <form  action="NetRulez.php" method="GET">
        <input type="number" name="i" value="" placeholder="enter real IP">
        <br/>
        <input type="number" name="port" value="<?php echo $port ?>" placeholder="enter port ID">
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Suche">       
    </form>
</div>
```

and here is my PHP

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['port']))
{
  $port = $_GET['port'];

  switch($port)
  {
    case ($port>= "1024" && $port<= "2031"): 
      echo "0";
        break;
    case ($port>= "2032" && $port<= "3039"): 
      echo "1";
        break;
    case ($port>= "3040" && $port<= "4047"): 
      echo "2";
        break;
    case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "3";
        break;
    case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "4";
        break;
    case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "5";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "6";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "7";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "8";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "9";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "10";
        break;
    case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "11";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "12";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "13";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "14";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "15";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "16";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "17";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "18";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "19";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "20";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "21";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "22";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "23";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "24";
        break;
   case ($port>= "" && $port<= ""): 
      echo "25";
        break;


    default: //default
      echo "within no range";
        break;
  }
}

?>
```

I will enter the port value of a different range. The3 echo continues till 64 and according to below switch case I have to write 64 cases and it's too lengthy. I tried few shortcuts but they are not working the way i wanted. Is there any option to write this in less code? Thanks a lot

Comment: Unless those very odd boundaries serve an actual purpose, a simple division might do.

Comment: can you explain it a little, if don't mind?Thanks

Comment: You can use an array of objects in json format such as [{min:'1024', max:'2031', value:'0'} ,{min:'2032', max:'3039', value:'1'},...] , and put it in a json file or in a variable, and use json_decode on it and then use foreach() to echo value if port is between min and max property, hope this hepls :)

Comment: can you attach some tutorial about an array of objects? I could not find it easily

Comment: I'll edit your code and add it as an answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) :)

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array with your ranges, like so:

```
$portRanges = [1024, 2031, 3039, 4047];

if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['port'])) {
    $port = $_GET['port'];
    foreach($portRanges as $key => $value) {
        if(array_key_exists($key+1, $portRanges) && $port >= $value && $port <= $portRanges[$key+1]) {
            echo $key;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array with port ranges, and use `array_filter` in combination with `current` to get the array index for the given port.

```php
$map = [
    ['from' => '1024', 'to' => '2031'],
    ['from' => '2032', 'to' => '3039'],
    // Add all ranges below
];

if(isset($_GET['submit'], $_GET['port'])) {
    $port = $_GET['port'];
    $index = current(array_filter($map, function ($value) use ($port) {
        return $value['from'] >= $port && $value['to'] <= $port;
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['port']))
    {
      $port = $_GET['port'];
      $json = file_get_contents("./port.json");
      $isValidPort = false;
      foreach($json as $obj){
        if($port>= $obj->min && $port<= $obj->max) {
           echo $obj->value;
           $isValidPort = true;
        }
      }
      if(!$isValidPort) {
        echo "within no range";
      }
    }

    ?>
```

The `port.json` file:

```
{
  [
    {min:'1024',max: '2031', value:'0'},
    {min:'2032',max: '3039', value:'1'},
    {min:'3047',max: '4047', value:''},
    ...
    {The last one with no ',' at the end}
  ]
}
```

Comment: The above code shows some error  ''Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()''